# Looking for hourly data of traffic congestion in Beijing

Tags: traffic

Does anyone know where to find it? I would take daily, but hourly would be better. Something like:

Oct 15, 2014 at 9pm: 1.4

Oct 15, 2014 at 10pm: 1.6

Comment: If you look for open data I think in China this is illegal. At least e.g. OpenStreetMap is